# How to downgrade the Webpack version used by Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

When I try to build my Nuxt.js project for production, I get this error:

```
Error: Path variable [contenthash:7] not implemented in this context: fonts/[contenthash:7].eot
    at fn (/home/mike/job/daily-fashion/node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js:45:11)
```

Googling the issue, I found [this conversation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/763), in which it's suggested to downgrade Webpack to 4.28 to solve the issue. The problem is, I don't see how to downgrade, given it's an internal dependency of Nuxt.js.

I'm using nuxt@2.11.0. This is how its dependencies appear in package-lock.json:

```
"@nuxt/webpack": {
      "version": "2.11.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nuxt/webpack/-/webpack-2.11.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512/yaT2lonYOQYUrsg==",
      "requires": {
         ....
        "webpack": "^4.41.3",
         ...
      },
```

Any suggestion how to make Nuxt.js used an older version of webpack? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me working this solution in package.json

```
    "nuxt": "2.3.4",
```